# Форматирование и восстановление системы

Tags: windows-7, форматирование

У меня вопрос такой. Хочу форматировать компютер. Есть некоторые вопросы.
-Файлы будут удалены только из C диска или из D тоже?
-После форматирование как восстановить драйвера в общем ПО(для входа в интернет программы так далее)
-И как форматировать. 
Если кто то ответит буду очень рад.

Comment: Форматировать  компьютер? Может форматировать жесткий диск? Вы можете форматировать как раздел (C), так и весь диск с его разделами. Если после этого вы установите чистую систему, то драйвера лучше устанавливать заново ручками. В зависимости от того, чего вы пытаетесь достичь, может хватить простой дефрагментации

Comment: Что я хочу скажу. У меня компютер Free DOS. установить хочу windows 10/7 но незнаю как и откуда. И после ПО откуда найти т.д все эти вопросы и Драйвера

Comment: Можете скачать windows 10 с официального сайта и установить. При надобности активировать через KMS. А как установить именно на вашу машинку - https://www.google.com/search?q=free+dos+%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+windows+10&oq=free+dos+&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.3377j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Форматируют не компьютер, а накопители (например, жесткие диски), причем каждый отдельно.
2. Буквы диска С и D могут относиться как к разным устройствам, так и к одному. Если у вас один жесткий диск (железка), а букв две или больше, то это называется "разделы". Их тоже можно форматировать отдельно.
3. У вас Windows. Windows не станет форматировать тот диск или раздел, на котором он находится. Вам для этого придется загрузиться с другого диска, с флешки, вынуть жесткий из компьютера и подключить его, как внешний, и так далее.
4. Форматируют по-разному, например, просто открыв "Компьютер" (там, где все диски указаны), нажав на нужный диск правой кнопкой мыши и выбрав "форматирование".
5. Перед форматированием нужно все данные куда-нибудь скопировать, потому что все будет оттуда выкинуто минуя какую-либо "корзину" и потеряется.
6. Драйверы нужно заранее найти в интернете.
7. Лучше всего ничего не форматировать, если сталкиваетесь с этим впервые. Превратите компьютер (временно, разумеется) в "кирпич" и будете расстроены, если что-то пойдет не так. А может быть, потеряете что-то нужное, что еще хуже.